# Previously trusted WiFi now asking me to select a certificate but the list is empty

Tags: macos, mac, network, wifi, certificate

I had this WPA2 Enterprise WiFi saved on my MacBook since forever, and the certificate was trusted first time I connected to it.

Suddenly the MacBook seems to have automatically forgotten the network (I went and looked in the saved networks and it was not there any more) for some reason, along with its certificate. If I try to manually connect to it, a message box pops up asking me to select a certificate. The list on the message box has nothing on it.

Their certificate is still valid and after double checking with my friend using the same network there has not been any change or update to the certificate. What do I do?